# Current best practices for loading content from another domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I'm tasked with working on a project where we want to laod content from another domain and push it into an id in our page.

Normally, I'd say have a proxy script to handle this but am curious if there is a better sol'n. Perhaps better to include page on other server that just document.writes out other content?

Is there a better current sol'n supporting say IE7+ and FF3+? Do YQL sol'ns support IE?

EDIT
It's a mixed RoR / PHP service - this section is PHP.  HttpHandler looks good - kinda like a local proxy using file_get_contents but with some extra functionality.

Re document.writing out html - this is the way I'm leaning torwards as JSONp might introduce headaches to end developers who will range greatly in skill set. Would I be insane to do this (ok, more insane)?!

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what server side code you are using but, in the past I've used an http handler in asp.net. Dave Ward did a good tutorial on this.

http://encosia.com/use-asp-nets-httphandler-to-bridge-the-cross-domain-gap/

This is good because it doesn't go through the entire page life cycle, so it is quicker than adding a page that serves up the data through response.write.

Answer (score 0):

Current best practice would be to use a jsonp service, *if* you have control over the other domain.  If you don't, then you're probably best off setting up a proxy service on your own domain.

Comment: we're not really processing any info. Is document.write too ugly? Mostly do server dev.

Comment: Well, document.write would be after you already have the content.  Since you've tagged jQuery in the question, it would be far easier to just use something like $('#container').html(<remote-content>);  The hard part is going to be actually *getting* the content, given the cross-domain situation.

Comment: I think my use of document.write isn't being clear. One could include a javascript file from an external domain that is document.writing onto the current page.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then, that's unfortunately not going to work the way you want.  The cross-domain policy is going to be enforced from the domain that the *page* was served, not the *JavaScript*.  Loading JavaScript from a remote domain is allowed, and it will be allowed to `document.write` all it wants.  It won't, however, be able to get around any Ajax-related cross-domain restrictions.